# Android Studio emulator doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just installed Android studio but when I try to run my app I get the following error message

```
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have an intel B960 ( I have read that this cpu doesn't support virtualization ).
I read many answers ( on stackoverflow too ), but it doesn't work:

- I checked that $ANDROID_HOME/Sdk/system-images/android-MNC/default/armeabi-v7a exists and is not empty.
- I installed ARM EABI v7a from the AVD Manager.
- I installed KVM by using: 
  sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils

But then I get this:

```
# kvm-ok 
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

what other do I have to try ?

Comment: I doubt the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` error is related to the (non-)presence of virtualization support. Have you tried setting that environment variable appropriately?

Comment: The `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable.

Comment: Yes but doesn t work

Comment: What did you set it to, and did the error change after you set it?

Comment: This variable was already set in the File -> Project Structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84372/discussion-between-xrobot-and-icktoofay).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your emulator is trying to use a version of the SDK that you don't have installed. You could either change the SDK of the AVD, create a new AVD with a different SDK, or install the appropriate SDK, and make sure that your environment variable is set correctly.

But frankly, I wouldn't bother. Get the [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) emulator instead. The difference between it and the built-in emulator can not be overstated. The free version has everything you need for basic tests. There are other emulators available, and I've heard they're all better than Android Studio's, but I only have personal experience with Genymotion. I ran a test where I started the Android Emulator first, and then the Genymotion emulator, and I had booted the Genymotion emulator and completed my test suite long before the Android Emulator finished booting.